# Atomic operation with hibernate

Tags: hibernate, stored-procedures, atomic

before write a record in db i have to do this task:

```
1- Read a max value of a field from a table
2- use this value to create new record
3- save the record
```

The value in step 1 must be unique.

The problem is that this task can be done by different client.

What is the best way to make this kind of operations atomic?

Thanks to all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestion:
- Add Unique constraint to the table's field
- select max value using Hibernate, assign the value to the entity and save it.

Comment: Field has unique constraint of course, and different client can select the same value and try to save it, this is the problem.

Comment: The first client will save the data and the second will get Exception (unique constraint violation), that is the point. But if You want to avoid these errors, You have to use some kind of unique key generator (for example, sequence in Oracle, which initial value is max (table.value))

Comment: I need to achieve this without throw an exception, but thank you.